# Why GCC (ARM Cortex-M0) generates UXTB instruction when it should know that data is already uint8

Tags: gcc, arm, cortex-m

I'm using a Cortex-M0 MCU from NXP (LPC845) and I'm trying to figure out what GCC is trying to do :)

Basically, the C code (pseudo) is as follows:

```
volatile uint8_t readb1 = 0x1a; // dummy
readb1 = GpioPadB(GPIO_PIN);
```

and the macro I wrote is

```
(*((volatile uint8_t*)(SOME_GPIO_ADDRESS)))
```

Now the code is working, but it produced some extra UXTB instruction I don't understand

```
00000378:   ldrb    r3, [r3, #0]
0000037a:   ldr     r2, [pc, #200]  ; (0x444 <AppInit+272>)
0000037c:   uxtb    r3, r3
0000037e:   strb    r3, [r2, #0]
105         asm("nop");
```

My explanation is as follows:

- load BYTE from address specified in R3, put result in R3    <-- this is load from GPIO register as BYTE
- load in R2 address of readb1 variable
- UXTB extends the uint8 value ??? But rotate argument is 0, so basically does nothing for uint8 !
- store as BYTE to R2's address (my variable) data from R3

Why does that?

First of all, it should know that data in R3 has just a BYTE meaning (it already generates LDRB correctly). Second, the STRB will already trim 7..0 LSB so why using UXTB ?

Thanks for clarifications,

EDITED:
Compiler version:

gcc version 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599] (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major)

I use -O3

Comment: what version of gcc and what command line options did you use?

Comment: please provide a complete repeatable example

Comment: This would be a good question, but you have made a complete mess of it! Please provide real code that we can look at. "the macro I wrote is": What macro?? What is its name? Where are you invoking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an extra instruction left in by the compiler and/or there is some nuance to the cortex-m or newer cores (would love to know what that nuance is).

```
#define GpioPadB(x) (*((volatile unsigned char *)(x)))
volatile unsigned char readb1;
void fun ( void )
{
    readb1 = 0x1A;
    readb1 = GpioPadB(0x1234000);
}
```

an apt gotten gcc

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (15:4.9.3+svn231177-1) 4.9.3 20150529 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c -mthumb so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.o


00000000 <fun>:
   0:   231a        movs    r3, #26
   2:   4a03        ldr     r2, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <fun+0x10>)
   4:   7013        strb    r3, [r2, #0]
   6:   4b03        ldr     r3, [pc, #12]   ; (14 <fun+0x14>)
   8:   781b        ldrb    r3, [r3, #0]
   a:   7013        strb    r3, [r2, #0]
   c:   4770        bx      lr
   e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  10:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
  14:   01234000    .word   0x01234000
```

as one would expect.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c -mthumb -march=armv7-m so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d so.o
so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   4a03        ldr     r2, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <fun+0x10>)
   2:   211a        movs    r1, #26
   4:   4b03        ldr     r3, [pc, #12]   ; (14 <fun+0x14>)
   6:   7011        strb    r1, [r2, #0]
   8:   781b        ldrb    r3, [r3, #0]
   a:   b2db        uxtb    r3, r3
   c:   7013        strb    r3, [r2, #0]
   e:   4770        bx  lr
  10:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
  14:   01234000    .word   0x01234000
```

with the extra utxb instruction in there

Something a bit newer

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

for armv6m and armv7m

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   231a        movs    r3, #26
   2:   4a03        ldr     r2, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <fun+0x10>)
   4:   7013        strb    r3, [r2, #0]
   6:   4b03        ldr     r3, [pc, #12]   ; (14 <fun+0x14>)
   8:   781b        ldrb    r3, [r3, #0]
   a:   7013        strb    r3, [r2, #0]
   c:   4770        bx      lr
   e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  10:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
  14:   01234000    .word   0x01234000
```

for armv4t

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   231a        movs    r3, #26
   2:   4a03        ldr     r2, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <fun+0x10>)
   4:   7013        strb    r3, [r2, #0]
   6:   4b03        ldr     r3, [pc, #12]   ; (14 <fun+0x14>)
   8:   781b        ldrb    r3, [r3, #0]
   a:   7013        strb    r3, [r2, #0]
   c:   4770        bx      lr
   e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  10:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
  14:   01234000    .word   0x01234000
```

and the utxb is gone.

I think it is just a missed optimization, peephole or otherwise.

As answered already though, when you use non-gpr-sized variables you can expect and/or tolerate the compiler converting up to the register size.  Varies by compiler and target as to whether they do it on the way in or the way out (when a variable is read or just before it is written or used down the road).

For x86 where you can access various portions of the register separately (or use memory based operands) you will see they do not do this (in gcc) even for cases when it clearly needs a sign extension or padding.  And sort it out down the road when the value is used.

You can search the gcc sources for utxb and perhaps see the issue or a comment.

EDIT

Note that clang takes a different path, it burns clocks generating the address but does not do the extension

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   f240 0000   movw    r0, #0
   4:   f2c0 0000   movt    r0, #0
   8:   211a        movs    r1, #26
   a:   7001        strb    r1, [r0, #0]
   c:   f244 0100   movw    r1, #16384  ; 0x4000
  10:   f2c0 1123   movt    r1, #291    ; 0x123
  14:   7809        ldrb    r1, [r1, #0]
  16:   7001        strb    r1, [r0, #0]
  18:   4770        bx  lr

clang --version
clang version 11.1.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git 1fdec59bffc11ae37eb51a1b9869f0696bfd5312)
Target: armv7m-none-unknown-eabi
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/llvm11armv7m/bin
```

I think it is simply an optimization problem with gcc/gnu.

Comment: OP question is about M0. no way to avoid https://godbolt.org/z/6xc1a4

Comment: armv6-m supports the utxb and as demonstrated is added.  But that does not exlpain the why it is added, appears to be a compiler issue.  (and gcc is well known for having these issues in the last decade or so).

Comment: You are right, and the answer is in the disclaimer: "There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE"

Comment: Well.. this confirmed my thoughts and since I'm not a ASM expert, thanks all for your comments. I would say that particular chipset manufacturer (ie. Texas, Nxp, etc) shall check what GCC is outputting a lot WAY BETTER since this single instruction can make a difference when toggling GPIO with few MHz...

Answer (score 1):

The "volatile" modifier is to blame. It does not call type extensions when written, because it doesn't make sense. But when reading, it always calls the extension. Because now the data is stored in a register, and must be ready for any operations, over the entire range of the visibility limit.
Abandoning "volatile" removes any additional operations on the data, but it can also remove the very fact of using the variable.

https://godbolt.org/z/cGvc8r6se

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, it should know that data in R3 has just a BYTE meaning

Registers are only 32 bits. They do not have any other "meaning". The register must contain the same value as the loaded byte - thus UXTB. Any other operation later (for example adding something requires the whole register to contain the correct value.

Generally speaking, using shorter types than 32 bit usually adds some overhead as Cortex-Mx processors do not do operations on the "portions" of the registers.

Comment: Disagree a little bit. Almost any "small core" like MCUs (not just Cortex) does have so called "optimized" instructions for manipulating 8 bits and 16 bits for exactly this purpose: data can have different meanings despite storage is 32 bits. I can read on 32 bits but my meaningful data is just 8 bits LSB (a I2C register) so the rest is just junk. That's why they have version or LOAD/STORE for 8,16 and 32. What is amazing is that GCC especially for mature cores like Cortex-M0 shall use that correctly.

Comment: I can't make sense of this at all. Although the OP's question is unclear on the details, it looks like the `uxtb` instruction is unnecessary here.

Comment: What you are saying isn't valid in this case. `ldrb` already sets the upper 24 bits to 0, and `strb` simply ignores them. There is absolutely no reason for `uxtb` regardless of the context.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, you need to file a bug at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/. But there are two difficult situations.

1. There are a lot of bugs related to "volatile", and all of them are not closed, and most of them are not even confirmed. As far as I understand, the developers are already tired of fighting windmills, and do not even react to it.
2. To successfully fix the problem - you need to find the extreme, the very one that wrote the root of evil. Authorship and all. You will not be allowed into someone else's branch, and only the most advanced are allowed into the master.
   But even before this moment, you need to find the reason for this behavior, and here again there are problems.
   The GCC code is huge, you can search endlessly.

My personal opinion: GCC treats ARM kernel registers as part of fast memory. This memory can be accessed via a physical address, which only adds to the problems. Well, if this is memory, and the dimension does not match, then, according to GCC, you need to add expansion commands.
Why does GCC use the correct commands when simply accessed? - well, he reads from memory to memory. Emphasis - "from memory". No matter what happens next, you need to read it right now.